# Javascript - Why Functions Vs Code Blocks are Needed Sometimes

Tags: javascript

Okay, so the only way to explain this is with an example. In javascript you can do something such as:

```
if(condition) {

}
```

The { and } are used to identify a code block. But in some cases such as this:

```
window.onload = function() {

}
```

You need the function() included. Why can't it just be:

```
window.onload {

}
```

Why the need for function() ? Also, I thought functions all have a name associated with them, and when that name is called the function runs, but why in this case is there a function with no associated name?

Comment: When doing window.onload = function() {}, you are setting onload to be an anonymous function that will be executed later.  You are not defining a function named window.onload.

Comment: Learn the difference between expressions and statements, that will clear things up. Then look up "anonymous functions", and "first-class functions"

Comment: In JavaScript function are full blown objects. JS variables have function-level scope (there's no block-level scope).

Comment: @PM77-1—javascript has execution context scope, where functions are one type of execution context. It's possible to have multiple global execution contexts (e.g. frames in a document) and eval (but that's evil so just don't mention it…). ;-)

Comment: That's just how it was designed. It emphasizes on creating the function object and doing something, which would be obscured by syntactical sugar like yours.

Comment: @RobG - All I was saying that in `for (var i=0, i<someThing, ++i) {//do something}` scope of `i` is **not** the block but the function it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

`if`, `for`, `while`, `try`, `catch`, etc. are all [**statements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) that modify the following statement. For example, an `if (condition)` statement will only execute the following statement if the *`condition`* expression evaluates to `true` (or is *truthy*). A [**block statement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) is a special type of statement that is used to group multiple statements together, allowing an `if` statement to apply to a larger section of your code.

However, `window.onload = function() { }` is an [**expression**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)—an *entirely* different construct. It's an assignment expression consisting of three parts, an assignment operator (`=`) an expression representing the value to assign (in this case a [**function expression**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)) and a reference to a variable or property to assign that value to (`window.onload`).

Note also that there is a difference between a **function expression** as mentioned above and a [**function statement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function), as this can often lead to some confusion. In both constructs, the curly brackets are required around the body (unlike in an `if` statement).

Answer (score 0):

`{` and `}` (also called "curly brackets") are [*punctuators*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.7), they are mostly used to denote a block of code, but have other uses.

Code blocks are statements that are conditionally executed and are used in various productions of the grammar, such as to enclose the statements related to an [*if statement*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5):

```
if (condition) {
  // statements to execute if condition is true
}
```

function bodies in declarations:

```
function foo() {
  // statements in function body
}
```

and expressions:

```
var foo = function () {
  // statements in function body
}
```

also in [*for*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.3), [*while*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.2) and [*do*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.1) loops, [*switch*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.11) and [*with*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.10) statements, and so on. Curly brackets are also used in [*object initialisers*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) (aka [*object literals*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5)):

```
var obj = {name: 'foo', age: 42};
```

and probably lots of other parts of the grammar that don't come to mind right now.

#### Edit

So having said all that, time for the questions:

> Why the need for function() ?

To indicate that the following code block is the body of a function, not some other production.

> Also, I thought functions all have a name associated with them,

For a function expression, a name is optional. The name is only available inside the function (except for certain versions of IE which had a bug that made the name global) to allow for recursive calling:

```
// Function expression
var foo = function bar() {
            // In here, call as bar or foo
          };

// Everywhere else, call as foo    
foo();
```

> and when that name is called the function runs, but why in this case is there a function with no associated name?

Function expressions are usually assigned to a variable and that name is used to call them. They are also passed in function calls, executed immediately or assigned to object properties where they can be called using normal property accessor syntax:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = function(){alert('My name is foo')};
obj.foo();
```

Function declarations create a variable in the scope of the declaration with the function name and the function object created from the body is assigned to that variable. Function declarations are processed before any code is executed.

There is quite a bit written about function expressions vs function declarations, see [*Named function expressions demystified*](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/) and [*A closer look at expression closures*](http://perfectionkills.com/a-closer-look-at-expression-closures/).

Comment: While all this is correct, and the links to the spec are very useful, I think it misses the crux of the question. OP is not asking 'Why do we have to use `{}`?', but 'Why do we have to use `function()`?'.

Comment: Thanks! Very informative. It's not that I don't know the syntax, it's that I just like to understand why my syntax is how it is.

Comment: If you don't like the syntax, [*CoffeeScript*](http://coffeescript.org) provides an alternative, as does the ES6 draft [*arrow function synax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: No I love the JS syntax! Is my favorite actually. I just had some confusions I needed cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

You think about Javascript (and maybe programming languages in general) the wrong way.

First of all, the `if` is a statement, a language struct that controlls the program flow. It is designed to look like `if (condition) code`.
`window.onload` is a variable. `window` is an object here, which can "contain" other variables (`onload` in this case), accessable with that dot notation.

In JavaScript you can assign almost anything to a variable, since everything is basically the same. This is confusing and totally awesome at the same time imo.

You **assigned** a function, which works via the given syntax `new function(params) {code}`. You could habe also done `window.onload = 5` or `window.onload = {a: 5, b: "foo", c: ["bar", "baz"]}`. (But that would cause runtime errors, because your browser fails to "run" that. Same error as if you'd try to run `var a = 5; a();`)